# Vue: Input Form in a component doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've got this code in my "ecedata" component with an input field:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-l-4">
        <p style="text-align: center">Data/day (GB)</p>
        <div class="form-input-set" style="background: white">
            <input v-bind:value="dataday" v-on:change="$emit('changedataday', $event.target.value)" type="number" class="form-input">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"ecedata" ,
    props: {
        dataday:Number,
    },
    data () {
      return {

      }
    },

}
</script>
```

And I'm calling the component in the main app.vue with:

```
<template>
    <ecedata v-bind:dataday="dataday" v-on:changedataday="vuedataday" ></ecedata>
</template>

<script>
  import ecedata from '@/components/ece/data/ecedata.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      ecedata,
    },
    data () {
      return {
          dataday:0,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      vuedataday() {
        alert(this.dataday)
      }
    },

  };

</script>
```

But it doesn't return a value on input in the form other than 0.
Where's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just binded the value from the parent to the child component.

You where almost there as you binded the `vuedataday` method as a callback of the `changedataday` event this function is receiving the value passed by the event.

```js
vuedataday(newDataday) {
    this.dataday = newDataday;
}
```

Another way to do two way binding is to use `v-model`.

```html
<ecedata v-model="dataday"></ecedata>
```

And in the child

```html
<input v-bind:value="dataday" v-on:change="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" type="number" class="form-input">
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Answer (score 1):

You defined state in your parent component, but never actually change it. The event on the other hand emits the changed value, but your `onChange` function never uses it.

You have to use the passed value and update the parents state.

```
vuedataday(value) {
  this.dataday = value;
  alert(this.dataday)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@input` event instead of `@change` event. In `@input` event you can call a function, inside function you can `$emit` parent method.

Your code should be write like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-l-4">
        <p style="text-align: center">Data/day (GB)</p>
        <div class="form-input-set" style="background: white">
            <input v-model="propsdata" @input="getValue" type="number" class="form-input">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"ecedata" ,
    props: {
        dataday:Number,
    },
    data () {
      return {
         propsdata: this.dataday
      }
    },

    methods: {
       getValue() {
        this.$emit('changedataday', this.propsdata);
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Your should use `v-model` in input binding and `props` variable to set another variable in child component. This style is good coding in `vue.js`. Thanks.